# Why i am getting 406 not acceptable response?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

here is my code

```
$.ajax({

                    url: "DataGridServlet.htm",
                    type: "GET",
                    traditional: true,
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    cache: false,
                    contentType:"application/json",
                    success: function (response){

                       console.log(response);
                   }
                   });

            });
```

and when i am sending request to controller.. every is working but wnem returning JSONObject i am getting thya status code as 406  not acceptable.

and below spring controller code

```
@RequestMapping(value="/DataGridServlet.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET,produces="application/json",headers="Accept=*/*")
    public @ResponseBody JSONObject getReturnData()
    {
       System.out.println("control came into conroller");
       JSONObject dataObject=new JSONObject();
       dataObject=jqTabsGridDataDao.getTabsData();
       System.out.println("controller data"+dataObject);
       return dataObject;
    }
```

any one can help me?

Comment: Remove everything other than the `url`, `type` and `success` arguments on the client and try again.

Comment: nooo same error coming and time controller is not calling

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
@RequestMapping(value="/DataGridServlet.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET,produces="application/json",headers="Accept=*/*")
```

to

```
@RequestMapping(value="/DataGridServlet.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET,produces="application/json",)
```

and this

```
$.ajax({

                    url: "DataGridServlet.htm",
                    type: "GET",
                    traditional: true,
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    cache: false,
                    contentType:"application/json",
                    success: function (response){

                       console.log(response);
                   }
                   });

            });
```

to

```
    $.ajax({
                url: 'DataGridServlet.htm',
                type: "GET",
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                success: function(result) {
                    alert(result + " result ");
                },
                error: function(resError) {

                    //alert(resError + " Error ");
                }
});
```